# Multiple row skipping in a long table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to add a summary of along table in the beamer template.
I wanted the table to look somewhat like this

+-------------+--------------+
|Heading 1|Heading 2|
| Entry1_1  | Entry1_2  |
| Entry1_1  | Entry1_2  |
~          ~           ~
~          ~           ~
| Entry8_1 | Entry8_2 |
| Entry9_1 | Entry9_2 |
+-------------+--------------+

The entries from row 3-7 are not important and hence, skipped. It can also be shown as sequence of "." (vertical dots). 
Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide small, complete document starting with `\documentclass{beamer}` all necessary packages `\begin{document}\begin{frame} ...\end{frame}` and ending with `end{document}`. Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following should act as a starting point of the solution to your problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Heading 1&Heading 2\\
    Entry1\_1 & Entry1\_2\\
    Entry1\_1 & Entry1\_2\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\dots}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\dots}\\
    Entry8\_1 & Entry8\_2\\
    Entry9\_1&  Entry9\_2\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```